# How to make a TCP SYN request with trace route

Tags: tcp, traceroute

I want to make TCP SYN requests using `traceroute` and discovered the flag `-T`. However, I don't know which values I have to use in order to make such requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -T option if you want to use TCP SYN for probing the remote address as shown in example below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# traceroute -T google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.31.206), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 gateway (192.168.0.1) 2.050 ms 3.041 ms 2.819 ms
2 10.234.0.1 (10.234.0.1) 3.771 ms 3.749 ms 3.716 ms
3 * * *
4 * * *
5 * * *
6 14.140.100.6.static-vegas.net.us (14.140.100.6) 12.234 ms 13.070 ms 12.644 ms
7 * * *
8 * * *
9 108.170.253.97 (108.170.253.97) 11.451 ms 108.170.253.113 (108.170.253.113) 13.403 ms 108.170.253.97 (108.170.253.97) 13.886 ms
10 74.125.253.13 (74.125.253.13) 9.523 ms 11.963 ms 11.388 ms
11 maa03s28-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.31.206) 10.477 ms 10.222 ms 8.391 ms
```

From [here](https://www.cyberithub.com/traceroute-command-examples-in-linux-unix/#Example_4_How_to_Use_TCP_SYN_for_Probes).